# When installing the software using NSIS how to set the progress bar text?

Tags: nsis

When installing the software I am seeing the progress of each dll or executable name. How can I hide that (for eg., in the below screenshot it is showing Extract res.dll 100%) and show my own progress text (for eg., Status: Installing EMR application)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetDetailsPrint` controls if instructions are displayed in the label and/or listbox.

```
Section
DetailsPrint "Start"
SetDetailsPrint listonly
DetailsPrint "Hello"
File 1234.txt ; List only
Sleep 3333
SetDetailsPrint none
DetailsPrint "World
File 5678.txt ; "Hidden"
Sleep 3333
SetDetailsPrint both
DetailsPrint "Finished"
SectionEnd
```